# Infinite sums: adding terms

Tags: limits, summation

I would like to know where I can find a formal treatment of an idea I had, assuming it makes sense. Consider the infinite sum

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

and define the partial sum

$$S_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

I guess that

$$R_N = S_N + \frac{1}{N}$$

should converge faster as $N\rightarrow\infty$. Does it make sense? Any formal theory? Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, it does converge faster, nice observation.

Comment: You could prove, for instance, that $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}N(\pi^2/6-S_N)=1$.

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}N^{k-1}\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^k} ~=~ \frac1{k-1}~.~$ See [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for more information.

Comment: The general topic here is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration

Comment: Please see the Euler-Mclaurin Sum formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since the sum is monotonically increasing, we can use the [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) formula,

$$(1) \quad \lim_{N \to {\infty}} \sum_{n=1}^N {1 \over {n^2}}= \lim_{N \to {\infty}} {{\pi^2} \over {6}}-1+\int_1^N {1 \over {n^2}} \ dn$$

We also know that $(1)$ becomes an equality in the limit. That's why we added a constant after applying the Euler formula.  It's the error term.

However, we know what the integral is,
 $$\int_1^N {1 \over 
{n^2}} \ dn=1-{1 \over N}$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{N \to {\infty}} \sum_{n=1}^N {1 \over {n^2}} = \lim_{N \to {\infty}}  {{\pi^2} \over {6}} -{1 \over N}$$

Since we'd like to retain non asymptotic approximations, we can't arbitrarily add terms. Rather, I'd suggest adding, ${1 \over N}$ to eliminate the ${1 \over N}$ term from the asymptotic expansion. This speeds up the convergence, as there will no longer be a subtraction term. Instead you'll have,

$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}} \sum_{n=1}^N {1 \over {n^2}}+{1 \over N}={{\pi^2} \over {6}}$$

I don't know if you think this defeats the purpose or not, but this is a more formal way. Below is a graph. Red is the partial summations of $\sum {1 \over n^2}$. Green is the newly adjusted terms. Orange is ${{\pi^2} \over 6}$.

[image]

Comment: After a thorough revision of this answer, the main results in it now hold (provided one skips the faulty uses of limits to mean something more than what they mean).

Answer (score 10):

Let us look at the truncation error. We have for $k\gt 1$
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\lt \frac{1}{k^2}\lt \frac{1}{(k-1)k}.$$
Using the partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{t(t+1)}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+1}$, and telescoping sums, we find that the truncation error $E_N$ when we truncate at the $\frac{1}{N^2}$ term satisfies the inequality
$$\frac{1}{N+1}\lt E_N\lt \frac{1}{N}.$$
Truncating of course underestimates the infinite sum. So the error when we add your suggested $\frac{1}{N}$ correction has absolute value less than $\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}$, that is, $\frac{1}{N(N+1)}$. For large $N$, this is much smaller than $E_N$, since $E_N\gt \frac{1}{N+1}$.

**Remark:** Nice idea! We used telescoping sums to give bounds on the truncation error. It is more common to use integrals.  For something much more elaborate that uses a similar insight, please look at Euler-Maclaurin summation.

Comment: Very good. More than I had hoped for!

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=1/x^2$.  Then, using the [Euler-Mclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula) we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}&=\int_1^Nf(x)\,dx+\frac12\left(f(N)+f(1)\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(N)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)+R_K\\\\
&=1-\frac1N+\frac12\left(\frac1{N^2}+1\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{K}B_{2k}\left(1-N^{-(2k+1)}\right)+R_K\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac1N+\frac{1}{2N^2}-\frac1{6N^3}+\frac1{30N^5}-\frac1{42N^7}+\frac1{30N^9}-\frac5{66N^{11}}+O(N^{-13}) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see that the modified truncated series

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}+\frac1N=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)$$

which converges faster than the un-modified truncated by an order of $1/N$, the former converging as $1/N$ while the latter converging as $1/N^2$.

And of course, we can improve even further using more terms in the Euler-Mclaurin Summation Formula.  Using the expansion in $(1)$, we have the following results for both the actual truncated sum and the terms from the Euler-Mclaurin Sum Formula (EMSF):

For $N=10$, $\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}\approx 1.54976773116654$, while the EMSF gives approximately $1.54976773116652$.

For $N=100$, $\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{n^2}\approx 1.63498390018489$, while the EMSF gives approximately $1.63498390021823$.

For $N=1000$, $\sum_{n=1}^{1000}\frac1{n^2}\approx 1.64393456668156$, while the EMSF gives approximately $1.64393456671489$.